# How to make a line or curve emit light with Three JS?

Tags: three.js

I'm looking for a way to make a line emit light, creating an effect such as this:

[image]

Here is what I am doing to create my line:

```
createLine() {
    // Create a curve with the points
    var curve = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(this.points);

    // Get the points
    var curvePoints = curve.getPoints(this.pointCount);

    // Create the geometry
    var curveGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curvePoints);

    // Create the material
    var curveMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color : 0x00AAFF,
    });

    // Create the line
    var line = new THREE.Line(curveGeometry, curveMaterial);

    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three.js does not give materials a "glow" effect just through the materials alone. What you need is a post-processing effect called "bloom", which can be added after the first render pass. See this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bloom#webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom

That example essentially does the following:

1. Sets up effect composer.
2. Renders normal scene
3. Takes result of first render, and adds "bloom" effect to it
4. Renders that result to screen

In that example's source code, the magic happens on lines 104 - 115, here it is commented for clarity:

```js
// Set up an effect composer
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

// Tell composer that first pass is rendering scene to buffer
var renderScene = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
composer.addPass( renderScene );

// Tell composer that second pass is adding bloom effect
var bloomPass = new THREE.UnrealBloomPass( new THREE.Vector2( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ), 1.5, 0.4, 0.85 );
composer.addPass( bloomPass );

// Tells composer that second pass gets rendered to screen
bloomPass.renderToScreen = true;
```

Comment: If you're here looking for making just the curve glow, and not everything in the scene, here's a great example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom_selective